# ASP.NET MVC 2 i18n

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, internationalization

I found the following page on i18n and ASP.NET: http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/55/internationalization/

The videos were very helpful although they apply to ASP.NET WebForms more than ASP.NET MVC, e.g., the videos show you how to internationalize controls rather than text -- which leads me to another realization: there isn't (or I couldn't find) a resources folder in my MVC applications -- just folders like AppData.

Is there a simple way (like in the videos) to internationalize plain text in ASP.NET MVC? If not, do I have to use some sort of ASP control?

Comment: Side question: Why can't I tag this question with i18n? Does that automatically go to internationalization (which I also tagged it with)?

Comment: Yes - i18n is a tag synonym for internationalization.  See the internationalization tag info page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=internationalization&sort=info&pagesize=15

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a guide here:

http://adamyan.blogspot.com/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html

Scott Guthrie linked to it recently via twitter, so I'll take it must be good.

Edit: remember to check the following post in the blog, as it tells you how to use routes instead of session values to configure the language for the user. http://adamyan.blogspot.com/2010/07/addition-to-aspnet-mvc-localization.html

Comment: Can't get to blogspot at my current location but I'll just preemptively accept your answer based on the URL for now. :P