# Babel (Python) extension to extract messages from ASP.NET (MVC ?) pages (for i18n)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, internationalization, gettext

I am about to start an [ASP MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) project that requires i18n support. In a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519654/asp-net-mvc-2-i18n) I knew of mostly everything I needed to get this done. I don't like MS approach (it's too complex) so I'd like to try [FairlyLocal](http://www.fairtutor.com/fairlylocal/). However it seems to use xgettext, which (AFAIK) doesn't extract messages inside *HTML* in *ASP* template files.

I use [Babel](http://babel.edgewall.org/) quite often so, I'd like to know if anybody knows an (message extractor) extension for *ASP* files (views) like those listed in [this page](http://babel.edgewall.org/wiki/BabelPlugins).

Answer (score 0):

FYI, you can point xgettext at any file you like, .html, .aspx or otherwise.

So yes, FairlyLocal can extract messages from those files.